# CSV file download as a txt file with downloadjs

Tags: reactjs, csv, download

I'm trying to download a .csv file with downloadjs npm but when I try to download. It is download as a .txt file.
Here is the code I'm using in the react

```
handleFileDownload = () => {
        axios.get(`${API_BASE_URL}/nominations/candidate-template/download`, {responseType: 'blob'}, {
        }).then((response) => {
            download(new Blob([response.data]), 'candidate_upload_template', response.headers['content-type']);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
    };
```

I have tried to csv mime type as below. but it didn't work ether

```
handleFileDownload = () => {
        axios.get(`${API_BASE_URL}/nominations/candidate-template/download`, {responseType: 'blob'}, {
        }).then((response) => {
            download(new Blob([response.data]), 'candidate_upload_template', "text/csv", response.headers['content-type']);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
    };
```

Here is the node backend code if it helps

```
const getCandidateTemplate = async (req) => {
  try {
      const docs = [];
        return docs.push({path: './src/templates/'+'candidate_upload_template', name: 'candidate_upload_template'});  
  }catch (e){
      throw new ServerError("server error");
  }
};
```

Does anyone know a solution for this issue
Thanks in advance

Comment: dod you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the download function is only supposed to take 3 args, last one is mime type. If you remove `response.headers['content-type']` from your second attempt does that change anything? Or I have also seen: `{ type: "text/csv" }` for declaring type.

Otherwise, maybe you can transform `new Blob([response.data])` into a string?